# Revert Linux Mint to initial stage

Tags: installation, linux-mint

How can I revert Linux Mint to its initial stage (The stage after successful installation of Linux Mint, no software installed at that time.) ?

Comment: You mean start over, by erasing & re-install it? Just do that (with a live iso again), backup your data / home files if they're worth keeping

Comment: *"no software installed at that time"* -- That is called an "empty or blank disk",